# how to use JCommander

Tags: java, jcommander

I have a sample code I downloaded and want to run it, the issue is its using JCommander to load some configurations, I do not have the configuration file yet it wants to load one, so I want to know; How can I use JCommander, i read the documentation and according to the site its a framework used to parse commandline parameters but I really do not understand what that means, this error is really holding me back from doing my project, here is the code requesting for the `.conf` file:

```
         BasicConfigurator.configure(); // TODO: config from options

        // Parse the command line options
        CliOptions options = new CliOptions();
        new JCommander(options, args);

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(options.configFile))
        {
            options.configFile = "/etc/car-counter/car-counter.conf";
        }

        // Read in the configuration
        Wini ini = new Wini();
        ini.getConfig().setMultiOption(true);
        ini.load(new File(options.configFile));

        new DefaultProcessor(ini).process();
```

and here is the CliOption Class

```
public class CliOptions
{
@Parameter(names = { "-c", "--config" }, description = "Sets the location of the configuration file.")
public String configFile;
```

}

Comment: so you don't have a requirement to **parse commandline parameters** and still you wish to use JCommander? JComamnder simplifies the way we code and handle command line args .

Comment: not that i dont, this is a sample project I am trying to run, its an Opencv sample project but unfortunately am prohibited to run it until I fix this error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\etc\car-counter\car-counter.conf (The system cannot find the path specified)` being generated by `JCommander`, I want to be helped on how make this code work, am not interested in `JCommander` but without it, it seems this sample code wont work and I wont learn what I want to learn from the sample code I ought to run

Answer (score 5):

The idea behind JCommander is to have a easy configurable option to provide command line parameters , their default values and so on.

Lets say your program needs an `int` parameter `jdbc_batch_size` with default value to be `2500` with an option to override that value . To achieve that, follow these steps,

1. you create your own class , lets call it `CommandLine` ,

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;

```
public class CommandLine {

 @Parameter(names = "-batchSize", description = "JDBC batch size",required=false)

 public int jdbc_batch_size=2500;

 }
```

2. Now, you create an object of above class ,  `CommandLine cli = new CommandLine();` in `main()` method

Create commander object `JCommander cmdr = new JCommander(cli, args);`

3. Now you can simply access `jdbc_batch_size` in `main()` method like ,

> int jdbc_batch_size=cli.jdbc_batch_size;

4. if you wish to `override` default value, you provide `-batchSize 1000` via command line

This is in a nutshell how `JComamnder` works.

Comment: so in my case am creating a file named configFile, but the issue is I cannot load the file in main, it always gives me the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\etc\car-counter\car-counter.conf (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Comment: and you try to provide configuration file via command line via `-c` or `--config` option? Does that file exist? `if (StringUtils.isBlank(options.configFile))
        {
            options.configFile = "/etc/car-counter/car-counter.conf";
        }`  looks for a file even if you don't provide or have one so its mandatory. What is the issue?

Comment: it seems like its mandatory most of the code is relying on the file that file, it does not exist thats a fact and I do not know what exactly its needed for and what it might contain

Comment: try to provide an empty file at that path